# Reducing an integral equation to a differential one

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

In my course about differential equations I have the following problem:

Find all the functions $f:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ such that the area below the graphic of the function in an interval $[a,b]$ (b>a) is proportional to the length of the interval itself. (with $f \in \mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R}))$

I have enunciate it as follows:

$\int_a^b{f(x)}dx = K (b-a)$

but I cant solve that with my knowledge in differential equiations. I have read in serveral places that integral equations and differential ones can be related between them but I can't think of any way to transform it to a differential equation

Comment: Here's a hint: suppose f(x) was equal to a constant. What would the integral be?

Comment: I have already seen that f(x) = K with K constant are solutions to that equation but I don't know if they are the only solutions (and why).

Comment: Suppose that there were two functions f_1(x) and f_2(x) both of which have the same answer K(a-b). Take the difference between the integrals of f_1(x) and f_2(x) and this has to be zero. What does that tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One form of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus says: 
$$\frac{d}{db} \int_a^b f(x)\,dx = f(b)\tag1$$
where $f$ is assumed continuous, and $b$ is taken as a variable with respect to which the derivative is taken.

Differentiating both sides of 
$$\int_a^b{f(x)}dx = K (b-a)\tag2$$
with respect to $b$ and using (1), you will arrive at the conclusion.

Comment: That's it. Thanks!