# Converting integral equation to differential equation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have obtained an integral equation that models a particular physical phenomenon. I wish to convert it into a differential equation so that I can solve it. Here's the equation defined for $z\geq z_0$:
\begin{equation}
g(z-z_0)=\int_{z_0}^{z}dt~f(t-z_0)g(z-t)
\end{equation}
After reading [post-1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406797/reducing-an-integral-equation-to-a-differential-one) and [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus), I thought this was the answer:
\begin{equation}
\frac{dg(z-z_0)}{dz}=f(z-z_0)g(0)
\end{equation}
but obviously this is incorrect, since upon integration again, $g(0)$ will be treated as a constant and so we do not get back the original integral equation. I have also read [post-2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394022/solve-integral-equation-by-converting-to-differential-equation), [post-3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264728/transforming-integral-equation-to-differential-equation), [post-4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352560/transform-integral-to-differential-equations), but still can't figure out the correct way. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am afraid what you want is not possible since the integral will remain after derivation. Observation: If $z_0 = 0$ and you apply the Laplace transform to your equation, you get $G(s) = F(s)G(s)$, that is $F(s) = 1$ or $G(s) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$g(z-z_0)=\int_{z_0}^{z}f(t-z_0)g(z-t)dt
$$

Let $z-t = y$
$$g(z-z_0)=\int_{0}^{z-z_0} f(z-z_0 -y)g(y)dy  $$

This implies that for $z-z_0  = t \geq 0$

$$g(t) = (g*f)(t)$$

Then apply Laplace to both sides

$$G(s) = G(s) F(s)$$

I think you can go from here.

Answer (score 3):

*As Friedrich Philipp commented.*

If you apply the fundamental theorem of calculus $$\begin{equation}
g(z-z_0)=\int_{z_0}^{z}~f(t-z_0)\,g(z-t)\,dt
\end{equation}$$
$$\begin{equation}
\frac{dg(z-z_0)}{dz}= f(z-z_0)\,g(0)+\int_a^z f(t-z_0)\, g'(z-t) \, dt
\end{equation}$$